# bash Add incremental number before string

Tags: bash, for-loop, while-loop

how can I add an incremental number in from of a list of strings?

**example:**

```
cat names.txt

alpha
beta
gamma
```

I need a loop, which inserts a number before the string.. like this

```
1. alpha
2. beta
3. gamma
```

could that be possible in bash?

Comment: How about `cat -n names.txt` ?

Answer (score 2):

The command line util `nl` (= number lines) is made exactly for this:

```
nl -w 1 -s '. ' names.txt
```

prints

```
1. alpha
2. beta
3. gamma
```